# Can gradient descent cause loss to increase in some situations?

Tags: objective-functions, backpropagation, gradient-descent

Is a gradient descent step always supposed to decrease loss? I can think of a situation where it would seem that gradient descent would increase loss but maybe it I am misunderstanding a part of gradient descent or backpropagation.

Sorry for the crude image.

[image: 1]

What I'm imagining is an inverted valley like shown. The red circle is the current loss, and the red arrows are the negative gradients of W1 and W2 in respect to the loss of the current step. The orange arrow is the added negative gradients. A function similar to the one I've drawn is loss = y - x^2